# How to read and write files with Flask with Ubuntu and apache server

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualenv, wsgi

I am trying to deploy an app that writes and reads png images with Flask. Locally I can run my script with no errors, except when I run it on my server.

I deployed using this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) on DigitalOcean. It uses apache, wsgi and virtualenv.

This an example of my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_file
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 100), (255, 255, 255))
    img.save('output.png')
    return send_file('output.png', mimetype='image/png')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I found out that what is causing the problem is `img.save('output.png')` I found also that if I try to load a font like: `font = ImageFont.truetype("Archive.otf", 60)` it doesn't work neither. My .png and .otf files are in the same folder as `__init__.py`

I guess I am messing up with the configuration or the directrory paths of apache. If I run `img.save` outside the flask enviroment it works, so it is not a problem with libraries or dependencies.

Comment: You haven't said what the actual problem is.

Comment: What happens if you provide absolute path to `img.save` like `img.save("/srv/my/server/path/output.png")` (of course, the correspoding dir should exists and your Apache have to have enough rights to write there)?

Comment: I found out the main problem is that apache or python does not have the rights to write and read files. I am trying to figure out how to do that but without success yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an absolute path, like `/var/www/somedir/somefile`. This is because Flask under Apache does not give Python a usable working directory.  I would suggest making the path configurable.

Comment: I only managed to save the files in /tmp, I think I need to give apache/python the rights to read and write files, but I am having trouble for that too.

Comment: You need to make sure that the Apache user has read/write access to the directories you're trying to use.